# Python Script - Findall

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The following script lists the output of all tags of `<ar-save-item>`.

```
def getrec():
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    recipe_list=[]
    recipes=[]
    result=[]
    key = "Paneer"
    url = "http://allrecipes.com/search/results/?wt="+key+"&sort=re"
    print(url);
    r=[]
    response = requests.get(url)
    try:
        result_page=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
        r=result_page.find_all('ar-save-item')
        for res in r:
            print(r);
```

However, I want to display on class-id values in tag. How to go about it?

The output looks like the following:

```
[<ar-save-item class="favorite" data-id="73715" data-imageurl="'http://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/250x250/00/42/82/428269.jpg'" data-name='"Paneer"' data-type="'Recipe'"></ar-save-item>, <ar-save-item class="favorite" data-id="212521" data-imageurl="'http://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/250x250/00/32/99/329922.jpg'" data-name='"Shahi Paneer"' data-type="'Recipe'"></ar-save-item>, <ar-save-item class="favorite" data-id="221826" data-imageurl="'http://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/250x250/01/03/63/1036376.jpg'" data-name='"Palak Paneer (Indian Spinach and Paneer)"' data-type="'Recipe'"></ar-save-item>
```

What is needed as outcome :

```
data-id="73715"
data-id="212521"
```

so on and so forth. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res` is a `dict`. You can get the value by `res['data-id']` or by using `get()` method as `res.get('data-id')`. It's better to use `get()` as it returns `None` if there is no `data-id` attribute but using `data-id` as key in `res` would raise an exception.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getrec():

    key = "Paneer"
    url = "http://allrecipes.com/search/results/?wt="+key+"&sort=re"

    response = requests.get(url)
    result_page = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
    r = result_page.find_all('ar-save-item')

    for res in r:
        print('data-id =', res.get('data-id'))

getrec()
```

**Output**

```
data-id = 73715
data-id = 212521
data-id = 221826
data-id = 212756
data-id = 232201
data-id = 222787
data-id = 232203
data-id = 240652
data-id = 138127
data-id = 256164
data-id = 221828
data-id = 212814
data-id = 106159
data-id = 159147
data-id = 86602
data-id = 237491
data-id = 213235
data-id = 228957
data-id = 228899
data-id = 232202
```

Comment: Error : ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'.

Comment: Because, you are doing `r.get()`. Use `res.get()`. check the code carefully.

Comment: Your code is giving output as data-id = None. i am using python 3.6

Comment: Copy the code correctly. I'm getting correct output here.

Comment: import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getrec():
 
    key = "Paneer"
    url = "http://allrecipes.com/search/results/?wt="+key+"&sort=re"
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    result_page = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
    r = result_page.find_all('ar-save-item')
    print(r)
    for res in r:
        print('data-id =', res.get('data-id'))
 
getrec()

Comment: try printing `res['data-id']`.

Comment: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Please edit your question and add your current code. I can't understand your code here.

Comment: In `Python 3.5` I'm getting the correct output. I don't think `Python 3.6` should be any different.

Comment: Try renaming `res` to `data`.

Comment: Thanks a ton, buddy! We ran it using Python 3.5 compiler and it ran successfully. I believe the issue was with IDE of Spider and not with Python.

Comment: @BirjuJani You're welcome. If my answer solved your problem then please consider accepting the answer.